# Pagination problem in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

In magento **pagination**,

When I pass **current page and per page**, its **showing accurate result** but when I pass per page value and current page value **if there is no record for current page its again showing previous record as was on previous page**, means its not considering total number of records.

**If there is only one record** and I pass **page no 2**, its **showing last page record instead of empty row** because there only one record.

Find below code:

```
public function getProductDetailAction()
        {

          $error = "false";
          $categoryid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
          $customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id');
          $per_page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('per_page');
          $current_page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('current_page');
          if( !$categoryid || empty($categoryid)){
              $error = 'true';
              $response['msg'] = "Category id is required.";
          }
          if( !$customer_id || empty($customer_id)){
              $error = 'true';
              $response['msg'] = "Customer id is required.";
          }
          $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
          $category->load($categoryid);
          $collection = $category->getProductCollection()
          ->setPageSize($per_page)
          ->setCurPage($current_page);
          $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
          foreach ($collection as $_product) {
              $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct( $_product->getId())->getData();
              // echo $stock["qty"];die;
              $product_data["id"] =  $_product->getId();
              $product_data["sku"] =  $_product->getSku();
              $product_data["name"] = $_product->getName();
              $product_data["type"] =  $_product->getTypeId();       
              $product_data["image"]  = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
              $product_data["url"] =  $_product->getProductUrl();
              $product_data["visibility"] =  $_product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(); //getVisibility(); 
              $product_data["weight"] =  $_product->getWeight();
              $product_data["stock"] =  $stock["qty"] ? $stock["qty"] : '';
              $product_data["status"] =  $_product->getStatus();
              $product_data["wishlist"] =  'no';

              /*Start Get rating of each product by product id. */
              $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addEntityFilter('product', $_product->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes();
                  $avg = 0;
                  $ratings = array();
                  if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                      foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
                          foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
                              $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
                          }
                      }
                      $avg = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
                  }

              $product_data["rating"] =  round($avg);


              $wishlist = $this->getWishListByCustomerId( $customer_id );

                foreach ($wishlist as $key => $value) {

                  if ( $value['product_id'] == $product_data["id"] ){

                      $product_data["wishlist"] =  'yes';

                  }
                }

              $product_data["category"] =  $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
              $product_data["weight"] = number_format((float)$_product->getWeight(), 2, '.', '');
              $product_data["description"]['short'] =  $_product->getShortDescription();
              $product_data["description"]['full'] = $_product->getDescription();
              $product_data["price"]["regular"] = $_product->getPrice();
              $product_data["price"]["final"] = $_product->getFinalPrice();
              $response['data']['Products'][]= $product_data;

          }
```

Comment: Hie Gopal, can you please look into my code where i am wrong. why my code is showing record if there is no record for given page. if there is only one record and i passed page no 2, its showing first page record.

Comment: if there is total 2 page and you type ?p=3 or greater then 2 it will shaw you last page means page 2

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

Your data

```
per page: 12
page no: 2
```

In collection :

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
   ->setPageSize($per_page)
   ->setCurPage($current_page);
```

If Collection size is 10 for given **category id** (means only one page exist) then if your given **page no** is greater then total no of page exist then it will show **last page from the page collection**

```
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
          ->setPageSize($per_page);
$last_page_no=$collection->getLastPageNumber();
if($last_page_no>=$current_page)
{
   //Your further code
}
```

find your code

```
public function getProductDetailAction()
{

  $error = "false";
  $categoryid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
  $customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id');
  $per_page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('per_page');
  $current_page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('current_page');
  if( !$categoryid || empty($categoryid)){
      $error = 'true';
      $response['msg'] = "Category id is required.";
  }
  if( !$customer_id || empty($customer_id)){
      $error = 'true';
      $response['msg'] = "Customer id is required.";
  }
  $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
  $category->load($categoryid);
  $collection = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->setPageSize($per_page);
  $last_page_no=$collection->getLastPageNumber();
  if($last_page_no>=$current_page)
  {
      $collection->setCurPage($current_page);
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
      foreach ($collection as $_product) {
          $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct( $_product->getId())->getData();
          // echo $stock["qty"];die;
          $product_data["id"] =  $_product->getId();
          $product_data["sku"] =  $_product->getSku();
          $product_data["name"] = $_product->getName();
          $product_data["type"] =  $_product->getTypeId();       
          $product_data["image"]  = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
          $product_data["url"] =  $_product->getProductUrl();
          $product_data["visibility"] =  $_product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(); //getVisibility(); 
          $product_data["weight"] =  $_product->getWeight();
          $product_data["stock"] =  $stock["qty"] ? $stock["qty"] : '';
          $product_data["status"] =  $_product->getStatus();
          $product_data["wishlist"] =  'no';

          /*Start Get rating of each product by product id. */
          $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $_product->getId())
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder()
            ->addRateVotes();
              $avg = 0;
              $ratings = array();
              if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                  foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
                      foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
                          $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
                      }
                  }
                  $avg = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
              }

          $product_data["rating"] =  round($avg);


          $wishlist = $this->getWishListByCustomerId( $customer_id );

            foreach ($wishlist as $key => $value) {

              if ( $value['product_id'] == $product_data["id"] ){

                  $product_data["wishlist"] =  'yes';

              }
            }

          $product_data["category"] =  $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
          $product_data["weight"] = number_format((float)$_product->getWeight(), 2, '.', '');
          $product_data["description"]['short'] =  $_product->getShortDescription();
          $product_data["description"]['full'] = $_product->getDescription();
          $product_data["price"]["regular"] = $_product->getPrice();
          $product_data["price"]["final"] = $_product->getFinalPrice();
          $response['data']['Products'][]= $product_data;

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Gopal, is it possible that collection will empty if no more record for next page instead of showing last page records from collection?

Comment: @KhalilurRehman find updated code. I am not aware of your further logic so you have to handel `$response['data']['Products'][]` properly